# How do I get the Midnight Launch achievement?

Tags: achievements, halo-4

The description for the achievement **Midnight Launch** is

> In mission 2, get significant air in the warthog at midnight.

Is "midnight" supposed to refer to a location in the level, or do I actually have to do it at real life midnight local time? What exactly do I have to do to get it?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me at all if it *was* midnight RL time. They had similar achievements in Halo 3, if I recall correctly.

Comment: The only one I can find was the 7 on the 7th achievement, and that was a Vidmaster

Comment: Just so you know, instead of doing the ramps, i just drove it off the cliff at 12:00. lulz it worked. Just drive it right off from where you got it and bam! 20 gs. enjoy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The requirement is in fact "real life midnight", although lucky for you your XBox doesn't really know what time it is.  To do so, the steps are:

1. Disconnect from Xbox live and go to your system setting to manually adjust time.  Set it around 5-7 min before midnight.
2. Go to Rally point Alpha on Requiem (Mission 2).
3. **Update**:  As Slenderman points out, the fastest/most  reliable way to "jump" is simply to **go off the cliff right next to where the Warthog spawns** - unless of course you've got something against respawning... :).
   Check your time by pressing the XBox button as you progress, to keep track.  You need to hit that jump in air at exactly midnight to get the achievement.  Naturally this may prompt some trial and error, but its pretty easy to drive off a cliff - so hopefully you get it on the first try.
   If you want to go the conventional route, you can head for the big jump a little later in the level.

This video shows all the details:

Comment: This should work. It just wouldn't put the date and time earned on the achievement panel, which is bad if you have OCD! =P

Comment: Yikes.  Talk about achievement farming...

Comment: I found a better solution that doesn't involve resetting the system clock: start playing several minutes before midnight and go through as normal, then when you are about to hit the jump, hit the guide button, wait until midnight, and then hit it again. I just got it doing that.

Comment: Also an option of course. The key is knowing where the big jump is, and timing. Some of us old folks don't stay up playing games till "real" midnight, too.

Comment: This is one of the silliest achievements I've seen for a while.... 10GS for completing a chapter, 20GS for doing this? The 4 seconds they spent devising the achievements list was worth it!

Comment: Surely there is some sort of boundary? E.G 00:00-00:01? Or 00:00-00:05 (Giving you 1 minute and 5 minutes respectively)?

Comment: @F4r-20 If I understand you correctly, the boundary is within the 1 minute.  When the clock strikes 12:01, you must restart and attempt again.  You can of course already be in the warthog waiting by 11:59 - so that's up to a minute grace period.